# Issue Tracking SonarQube 6.7

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I am using SonarQube version 6.7

How do you track and old issue and new issue in issue lifecycle?

Here statement from SonarQube document:

> For each file (after detection of file renaming), the algorithm takes
>   the list of base issues from the previous analysis, and tries to match
>   with raw issues reported by the new analysis. The algorithm tries to
>   first match using the strongest evidence, and then fallback to weaker
>   heuristics.
>
> - if the issue is on the same rule, with the same line number and with the same line hash (but not necessarily with the same message) > MATCH
> - detect block move inside file, then if the issue is on the same (moved) line and on the same rule (but not necessarily with the same
>     message) > MATCH
> - on the same rule, with the same message and with the same line hash (but not necessarily with the same line) > MATCH
> - on the same rule, with the same message and with the same line number (but not necessarily with the same line hash) > MATCH
> - on the same rule and with the same line hash (but not the same message and not the same line) > MATCH
>
> Unmatched "base" issues are closed as fixed.
>
> Unmatched "raw" issues are new.

From statement above, I assume:

1. There are two list, base issue and raw issue where base issue will be matched to raw issue.
2. There are 4 element will be checked : rules, line number, line hash, message. I assume message is comment.
3. It will check algorithm from first algorithm to last, since the strongest evidence is the first algorithm. If First algorithm is unmatched, it will check second algorithm and so on.
4. If first algorithm is matched, it will stop there and consider it as old issue. And if all algorithms is unmatched, it will consider it as new issue.

Based on assumption, I am trying to figure out how to form cases where it will matched until 4th algortihm and matched on 5th algorithm? Can anybody confirm or correct me? And please kindly give me some cases to help me understand.

Comment: I don't answer to your question, but https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/sonarqube/mzId9fnN9pI/FLGRMvsVCAAJ is more or less related. It mentions the ticket SONAR-2812 which introduced the 5th step.

Comment: Okay, thank you. I will try looking more in groups google forum.